# Where can I learn more about degeneracy pressure?

Tags: pressure, nuclear-physics, astrophysics, resource-recommendations, neutron-stars

I would like to know where I can learn more about degeneracy pressure.Is it a fundamental constant that is unique for all elementary particles.

Is there a formula for it?.

How is it derived?

If I was to find the average neutron degeneracy pressure of the crab pulsar ($r=0$ to $r=r_0$) how would I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Kip Thorne's book on black holes and time warps contains a pretty good explanation of this topic.